# Heroku deployment on wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

following an upgrade of my app, I fail to deploy the application on ruby version 3.0.4 on Heroku. Heroku says

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
            Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.3.25
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
###### WARNING:
       Your app was upgraded to bundler 2.3.25.
       Previously you had a successful deploy with bundler 2.2.21.
       If you see problems related to the bundler version please refer to:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues
       Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://heroku-buildpack-ruby.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-20/ruby-2.7.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
       Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://heroku-buildpack-ruby.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-20/ruby-2.7.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
 !
 !     The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist on this stack.
 !     
 !     You are trying to install ruby-2.7.0 on heroku-20.
 !     
 !     Ruby ruby-2.7.0 is present on the following stacks:
 !     
 !     - heroku-18
 !     
 !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
 !     
 !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

I am confused as to why/ how Heroku is looking for this Ruby 2.7.0 version (still)

**.ruby-version file**

`Ruby-3.0.4`

**Gemfile**

`ruby '3.0.4'`

**Gemfile.lock file**

```
RUBY VERSION
ruby 3.0.4p208
BUNDLED WITH
2.3.25
```

There is nothing popping up if I call grep -r "ruby 2.7.0" on the code pushed to heroku.

I have tried to see what can be wrong with the Heroku environment and tried several things

**Removing buildpack**
I ran

`heroku buildpacks:remove heroku/ruby --app myapp`

to remove build back but I get

```
Error: Buildpack not found. Nothing was removed.
```

I have setup different environment variables to make sure Heroku looks for 3.0.4 including

```
CUSTOM_RUBY_VERSION:      3.0.4
ENV[CUSTOM_RUBY_VERSION]: 3.0.4
```

I do not get where this reference to buildpack on AWS. I suppose this is Heroku stuff. I do have files on the app stocked on AWS S3 but I do not think there is a relationship here. Any suggestion on where to dig further would help. Thank you!

Comment: Try to keep only the Ruby buildpack. And in your `.ruby-version` file write the ruby version as a single word `ruby-3.0.4`

Comment: Also, look at the version of ruby in your Gemfile, in case that hasn't been set correctly

Comment: This does not seem to help. Both the Gemfile.lock and Gemfile say ruby 3.0.4. I am still really clueless how come Heroku is picking up 2.7.0.

Comment: Do you have `rvm` installed on your machine, or the file(s) `.ruby-version` or `ruby-version`? If you do, then it should be safe to delete them and push again